# hibernate criteria for multiple select on same table

Tags: hibernate, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a case where I need to find out the difference between the same field of the table for different versions. 

For example:

I have a table called BankAccount with fields like

> acount_no
>   , 
>   balance
>   ,
>   date etc.

Now what I want to achieve is basically run a select on this table for two different dates and find out the difference between the balance field value for date 1 and date 2.

More like:
    `a.balance - b.balance as balance_difference`.


I know, I can run the two selects using one as a detached criteria, where I at least get the common records between the two dates. My problem is finding the difference and using "alias" in the criteria since I have never done this before and haven't been able to understand or gather much from other online sources.

Any help is much appreciated and thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding what you want to achieve is the `hql` something like the following

```
select (coalesce(case when a.date=?1 and a.account_no=?3 then a.balance end), 0) - coalesce(case when a.date=?2 and a.account_no=?3 then a.balance end), 0) AS balance_difference from BankAccount a
```

Comment: I can get the result using normal sql string, but I am looking for some help where I can achieve the same using Hibernate Criteria API.